# Angular use one module of a library

Tags: angular, primeng

I want to use **PrimeNG** for my next project. It has several modules for each component (ie: `ButtonModule`, `TableModule` and so on). If I want to use only one module, will all the library get loaded into my application? How this will be done by Angular?

Answer (score 1):

It’s very simple you use the modules you want.
In your example it’s Prime-NG. It’s basically a bootstrap. You chose your own use of modules inside it. Just keep in mind that some modules need one another for it to work. So look out for what you need to import into the ngModule.

Hope this helps you understand how bootstrap and modules work.